# Why is R data.table adding columns to a another data table that I did not reference?

Tags: r, data.table

I have an original data table `dt1` that contains column `x`.  I want to create another data table called `dt2` that contains `x` and the first lag of `x`.  When I execute the following code, I obtain `dt2` as desired, but I find that `dt1` has also become `dt2`--I don't want this to happen.

```
library(data.table);

x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1);
dt1 <- data.table(x);

dt2 <- dt1;
dt2[, lx:= shift(x, 1, type= "lag")];

identical(dt1, dt2); # evaluates to TRUE
```

Am I missing something fundamental about how data table works? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `data.table` changes its values by reference. If you'd like to retain a copy of the original, you should use `copy`:

```
library(data.table)         
DT1 <- data.table(x = 1:100)
DT2 <- DT1                  
identical(DT1, DT2)         
#> [1] TRUE
DT1[, y := x + 1]           
identical(DT1, DT2)         
#> [1] TRUE
DT2 <- copy(DT1)            
DT2[, y := x + 2]           
identical(DT1, DT2)         
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I spent hours getting confused and angry about this--thank you @Hugh!